# Breaking up transformations

Tags: css, transform

I have 48 elements and they all have the same animation which is a transformation in the Y axis but they each have a different rotation

```
transform:rotate(0deg) translateY(-105px);
...
@keyframes mov {
  0%,65%,100% {transform:rotate(0deg) translateY(-105px);}
  15%, 50% {transform:rotate(0deg) translateY(105px);}
}
```

and it would be horribly inefficient if I were to have that for each element - is there a way I can have `transform:rotate(0deg)` in one place and `translateY(?px);` in another place?

---

Current solution: element in an element, first is rotate and the second is translateY

Comment: you can use different keyframes and then different classes say `mov` for `translateY` and `rot1`,`rot2`.. etc for rotation.

Comment: @tkay I suspect that won't work. http://jsfiddle.net/Ajedi32/sLuqaf7w/

Comment: okay. my mistake. what about nesting all these rotating elements inside a container div which translate along y axis? like this http://jsfiddle.net/tkay/sLuqaf7w/1/

Comment: wrapping it could be a solution

Comment: Wrapping it all up is my current solution (see bottom of post), thank you all for your help